# Communicate with WCF Windows Service in VB6?

Tags: wcf, vb6, windows-services

I have a VB6 application that I want to communicate with a WCF Windows Service that I have written which imports Security Certificates.  The only function in the service takes two string arguments.  I have been having a lot of difficulty getting the two programs to communicate however.

In VB.NET, it is easy, just make a reference to the service as you would a web service.  In VB6, however, it is not so simple it seems.  Searching only seems to pull up examples of how to WRITE a Windows service in VB6.

Anyone know how this is done?

Comment: Do you know http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/wcf/thread/d5c5ab13-bf07-4047-8be7-c697f8f4c564 and http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=558239 ?

Comment: Yeah I saw variations of both of those.  I have tried using the SOAP toolkit, without success.  I could not figure out how to get the wsdl generated at runtime (ala ServiceModelSamples/service.svc?wsdl) and the wcf wsdl that is generated when you run svcutil does not have everything necessary to connect.  They seem to be geared specifically to webservices (even though I have communicated with the windows service in this case almost exactly as I have with webservices)...

Comment: .Net WCF is not really very interoperable with other Web Services toolkits in general.  A search of the Web for "WCF interoperability" helps reveal the real story.

Comment: @BobRiemersma: that's nonsense if not backed up by facts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easyest way I have found to access a WCF service from VB6 is to create a .Net ComObject wrapper for the service client. Then in VB6 all your are doing is a create object and calling some methods on the object. All the WCF work takes place in the .Net com object.

Comment: Sounds intriguing.  How is that done?  I have never done it before.

Comment: Simply create the WCF client to the service in a separate project [as described in this link.](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Dec/16/WCF-Clients-and-COM-Interop) [Register the .NET assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jigarme/archive/2008/04/28/how-to-register-net-assembly-for-com-interop.aspx) as a type library which you would then link from the VB6 app.

Comment: So then VB6 app will call the client, which will in turn call the service?  In that case, I think I will just put the services functionality in the registered assembly and skip a step.  Honestly I thought this would have been easier.