# Consume web service using VB6

Tags: web-services, vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to consume a web service from VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122607/what-is-the-best-way-to-consume-a-web-service-from-vb6)
>   [Communicate with WCF Windows Service in VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615540/communicate-with-wcf-windows-service-in-vb6)

I have a simple web service (asp.net 2010) that will just return the inputted string.

the problem is i want to display it on vb6 (maybe on a msgbox) but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516119/get-post-to-restful-web-service) which talks about hitting a RESTful web service from VB6. It uses the MSXML library which seems at first glance to wrap the actual act of sending an HTTP request.