# Access to a WCF web service in VB6

Tags: wcf, web-services, vb6

I am very basic in VB6 so sorry if I am asking an obvious question!

We have an old VB6 application and currently we need to do some re-enhancements in it. I want to somehow connect it to a WCF webservice to send and get files (WCF will take care of loading and storing them in DB).

Based on my researches, it is possible based on [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615540/communicate-with-wcf-windows-service-in-vb6) and some others, Now I am wondering if is it required to have .NetFramework installed on systems to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RESTFUL WCF Service and set the UriTemplate attribute for the method(OperationContract).

Full [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/RestServiceAPI.aspx) for creating REST service

Comment: In your scenario isn't it required to install .NetFramework on client computers?

Comment: @amirmoradifard No its not required to install .net framework on client computers, as you are using VB6

Answer (score 1):

[The article you have linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615540/communicate-with-wcf-windows-service-in-vb6) suggests that the VB6 code should call a .Net wrapper for the WCF service.

If you do that, then yes, certainly you will require the .Net framework to be installed on the machine that runs the VB6, because that machine will also have to run the .Net wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, Could you suggest a better and easier way to do so. Installing .Net framework for all of them is somehow impossible (there are over 2 hundreds of customers)

Comment: @amirmoradifard I don't know of one myself. You could post this as another question - `How to communicate with a WCF Windows Service in VB6, without a dependency on .Net`