# WCF: The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, web-config

I have a wcf service

there is a method which gets base64 string to upload a file my file's size 100kb it may be larger in time

i got the error message: The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large
while try to get HttpWebResponse

this is my wcf service web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  
  <webHttpBinding>
    
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity" allowCookies="false" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
       maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="FHServices.FHSmartService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="FieldHoundServices.IFHSmartService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/FHServices/FHSmartService.svc/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

what is my mistake?

---

#### solved

i found my mistake
i remove these codes

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
  </security>
```

i think transport mode for https and we have no ssl so we dont need transport mode. anyway after i remove it, everything seems ok now

Comment: Could be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884235/wcf-how-to-increase-message-size-quota increase the message size the server allows you to transmit.

Comment: i set maxReceivedMessageSize to 2147483647 but still same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513785/calling-wcf-service-from-excel-gives-error-on-received-message-size/23514486#23514486

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign a defined `WebHttpBinding` configuration to your endpoint, so the endpoint uses the default values for the binding.

You can tell the endpoint to use your binding congfiguration by specifying it in the `bindingConfiguration` attribute on the `<endpoint>` element, like this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity"
          contract="FieldHoundServices.IFHSmartService" 
          behaviorConfiguration="web">
</endpoint>
```